# Heroku not applying environment variable changes in Okta OAuth 2.0 PKCE VueJs app

Tags: heroku, okta

I' trying to execute the OAuth 2.0 PKCE demo with a VueJs app outlined here:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce

https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-auth-js-pkce-example

Once in the Heroku App I have these Environment Variables:

[image]

Everything appears to be running fine except for the fact that the variables OKTA_CLIENT_ORGURL and OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER were refering to an incorrect dev-XXXXXX address, the correct one is the one shown on the picture (dev-371167), before it was someone else's url (dev-739491) for some reason.

The problem is that after making the changes shown in the image to the correct dev url, it's still making the calls to the old dev-739491 url.

Heroku doesn't seem to be refreshing or making the desired changes in the app.

Am I missing an option to refresh? Is it possible to rebuild so it reads the new changes? Could the problem be in the code/build itself?

Thanks.

EDIT: As per the suggestion in the comment I turned the app off then on again and it still didn't make the changes.

This is what my screen looks like:

[image]

EDIT 2: I have since deployed the same app two more times and reading the build logs it assigns a random CLIENT_ID and URls. Each deployed app has a different pair of these. I don't know where they come from.

Comment: Restart your app manually here: https://i.imgur.com/XYWjelF.png
If it does not take the new URL then you need to deploy/build again. The issue is that inside your `package.json` the build script is only run once and it doesn't rebuild when you just change the environment variables.

Comment: I updated my post to show what the screen you suggested looks like on my end, I switched it off and on and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the Okta Heroku Add-On. I'm looking into the behavior you're seeing.

When you change the environment variables, heroku should restart your app automatically.

So, the two issues are that the environment variables didn't match you saw in Heroku didn't match with what you expected them to be and that the app doesn't seem to be picking up on the environment variables.

How did you know that dev-371167 was the correct org and that dev-739491 was incorrect?

When you say you deployed the app two more times, what exactly are you doing to deploy? Are you using the Heroku cli?

Comment: One quick follow up: Looking in the okta heroku add-on database, I only see dev-739491. So, it seems that dev-371167 was NOT created with the add-on. Is this an org that you already had previously? The Okta Heroku Add-On's purpose is to allocate and Okta Org and to create some default OIDC applications to make it easier to deploy your app.

Comment: When you open an Okta account it gives you you're own url in the form of, as is my case, https://dev-371167.okta.com/. So the point of the excercise is to load the Vue app which has links to either the implicit or pkce flow, after clicking it sends you to the your okta login, which lives in the mentioned url, then redirects back to the vue app with the user info. -- On the vue app's github page, on the readme, it has a deploy to heroku button, after clicking it deploys the app all on its own, so I did this severa times, and each time a different client id and dev url were assigned.

Comment: BTW, it could perfectly be an issue with the Vue app, I have already gotten around this problem. There's 3 constants that you can change in the code where you configure the clientid, redirect url, and callback path. So I forked the repo and changed those variables to my specific values and now it's working. -- So maybe the Vue app is the one not picking up on the Heroku variables.

Comment: FWIW, I created a heroku app and okta org from scratch from the github repo you referenced above and the app worked as it was supposed to.

From context, it seems like you had an existing okta org, but that you used the purple deploy button from github repo. As configured, it would have created a NEW Okta org. So, that's why the env variables were set to that new org. That said, you should be able to change those env variables to an existing org and have everything work. DM me @afitnerd and we can look at it together.

Comment: There shouldn't be any hard coded constants in the Vue app. They should all be pulled from environment variables, which are set on Heroku. Here's an example: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-auth-js-pkce-example/blob/master/src/auth/index.js#L5 What did you find that you needed to update?